# Puppet: Nagios with regex node names

Tags: puppet, nagios, regex, hiera

I am configuring a puppet master and want to rely heavily on hiera. Many of my systems will be almost identical due to being scalable.

I have therefore created node manifests which use regex rather than having individual node configurations for each server. I then use hiera to set specific configuration values for each server.

I seem to be running into trouble when trying to use nagios to monitor them as it appears most nagios modules create the client config on the server by looking through the client node manifests. As I don't have individual client node manifests I'm not sure how this will work.

Should I be looking at storing a list of clients as an array in hiera which the server manifest looks up? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You would have each agent's manifest [export](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_exported.html) its nagios configuration based on its hiera data.

The nagios server will then [collect](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_exported.html#collecting-exported-resources) all configuration items.

Make sure that all `nagios_*` resources have unique names, e.g. by including the value of the `$fqdn` fact in the respective resource name.